# How can I remove everything except a selected tag from a html file with python?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, python-3.x

If I have this division:

`<div class="wikicontent" id="wikicontentid">`

How can I use Python to print just that tag and its' contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import bs4

soup =  bs4BeautifulSoup(html_content);
result = soup.find("div", { "class" : "wikicontent", "id" : "wikicontentid" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module.

```
>>> import bs4
```

Suppose we have a document that contains a number of divs, some which match the class and some which match the id, and one that does both:

```
>>> html = '<div class="wikicontent">blah1</div><div class="wikicontent" id="wikicontentid">blah2</div><div id="wikicontentid">blah3</div>'
```

We can parse with Beautiful Soup:

```
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

To find all the divs:

```
>>> soup.find_all('div')
[<div class="wikicontent">blah1</div>, <div class="wikicontent" id="wikicontentid">blah2</div>, <div id="wikicontentid">blah3</div>]
```

This is a `bs4.element.ResultSet` that contains three `bs4.element.Tag` which you can extract via the `[]` operator.

To find everything matching a given id, use the `id` keyword argument:

```
>>> soup.find_all(id='wikicontentid')
[<div class="wikicontent" id="wikicontentid">blah2</div>, <div id="wikicontentid">blah3</div>]
```

To match a class, use the `class_` keyword argument (note the underscore):

```
>>> soup.find_all(class_='wikicontent')
[<div class="wikicontent">blah1</div>, <div class="wikicontent" id="wikicontentid">blah2</div>]
```

You can combine these selectors in a single call:

```
>>> soup.find_all('div', class_='wikicontent', id='wikicontentid')
[<div class="wikicontent" id="wikicontentid">blah2</div>]
```

If you know there is only one match or if you are only interested in the first match, use `soup.find`:

```
>>> soup.find(class_='wikicontent', id='wikicontentid')
<div class="wikicontent" id="wikicontentid">blah2</div>
```

As before, this is not a string,

```
>>> type(soup.find('div', class_='wikicontent', id='wikicontentid'))
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

but you can turn it into one:

```
>>> str(soup.find('div', class_='wikicontent', id='wikicontentid'))
'<div class="wikicontent" id="wikicontentid">blah2</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

To download the page source use http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/,  for parsing html/css tags use http://lxml.de/.

```
import requests
import lxml.html

dom = lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get('http://theurlyourscraping.com').content)
wikicontent = [x for x in dom.xpath('//div[@class="wikicontent"]/text()')]
print wikicontent
```